# python if/else statement with exception that keep elements if exist in another sub-list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Let us say I have the following tokens in list :

```
['I', 'want', 'to', 'learn', 'coding', 'in', 'r', 'and', 'c++', 'today', ',', 'and', 'then', 'I', "'ll", 'be', 'learning', 'c#', 'and', 'c']
```

I want to remove all tokens of length < 2 but want to keep elements of this sub-list:

```
['r','c','js','c#']
```

How can I do this in a single python list-comprehension ?

Comment: `[i for i in lst if len(i) >= 2 or i in {'r','c','js','c#'}]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with two conditions.

```
lst1 = ['I', 'want', 'to', 'learn', 'coding', 'in', 'r', 'and', 'c++', 'today', ',', 'and', 'then', 'I', "'ll", 'be', 'learning', 'c#', 'and', 'c']

lst2 = ['r','c','js','c#']

res = [l for l in lst1 if (len(l)>=2) or (l in lst2)]
print(res)
```

---

```
['want',
 'to',
 'learn',
 'coding',
 'in',
 'r',
 'and',
 'c++',
 'today',
 'and',
 'then',
 "'ll",
 'be',
 'learning',
 'c#',
 'and',
 'c']
```